# Is there any method to hide or remove checkout step 3,4,5 in opencart

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart

I am developing a simple website in opencart and I need to remove a different step on checkout. Customer can simply checkout and fill account information to confirm checkout or direct checkout after.

Modify on checkout.php :

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-payment-method .panel-body').html(html);

                        $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

                        $('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-method\']').trigger('click');
                        $('#button-payment-method').trigger('click');
                        $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                        //$('a[href=\'#collapse-checkout-confirm\']').trigger('click');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

It works, but how can I solve it in a better way?